# How to structure and extract shadow information from VTK using Python WX?

Tags: python, shadow, vtk, wxwidgets

I am attempting to evaluate shading on solar panels from 3D models of a satellite visualised in VTK with wxpython.  To do so, I have models of the positions of the panels and have placed a light source to create a distinct shadow to evaluate shading from a particular direction.  Ultimately, I hope to extract a power estimate based on the fraction of shadowing on the area.

I have hit a challenge, which I would appreciate the community input as to how best to properly implement and extract the shadow information which must be generated by the graphics engine, i.e. to then extract points of lit and unlit areas for each polygon or actor.

A simplified example is below, where I am using a light source to highlight two cubes (based on this [example](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/lights-cameras-action-a-simple-example-to-embed-vtk-with-wxpython/)).  Firstly, I am not seeing any shadowing from the cube1 upon cube2 (which I would expect), and secondly, I cannot figure how to extract this information if I could.

```
import wx
import vtk
from vtk.wx.wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor import wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor

class p1(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        #to interact with the scene using the mouse use an instance of vtkRenderWindowInteractor.
        self.widget = wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self, -1)
        self.widget.Enable(1)
        self.widget.AddObserver("ExitEvent", lambda o,e,f=self: f.Close())
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.widget, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.isploted = False

    def renderthis(self):
            # open a window and create a renderer
            self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
            self.widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)

            #Create a cube (to shadow)
            cube1 =vtk.vtkCubeSource()
            cube1.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 2)
            cube1Mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
            cube1Mapper.SetInput(cube1.GetOutput())
            cube1Actor = vtk.vtkActor()
            cube1Actor.SetMapper(cube1Mapper)
            self.ren.AddActor(cube1Actor)

            #Create a second cube (to be shadowed)
            cube2 =vtk.vtkCubeSource()
            cube2.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
            cube2.SetXLength(2)
            cube2.SetYLength(2)
            cube2Mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
            cube2Mapper.SetInput(cube2.GetOutput())
            cube2Actor = vtk.vtkActor()
            cube2Actor.SetMapper(cube2Mapper)
            self.ren.AddActor(cube2Actor)

            # add axes and view point
            axes = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
            self.marker = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
            self.marker.SetInteractor( self.widget._Iren )
            self.marker.SetOrientationMarker( axes )
            self.marker.SetViewport(0.75,0,1,0.25)
            self.marker.SetEnabled(1)

            # add distant light source
            self.light = vtk.vtkLight()
            self.light.SetPosition(0, 0, 100)
            self.light.SetColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            self.ren.AddLight(self.light)

            # may need to add something for vtkShadowPass() here?

            # then would extract the resultant filter?

            self.ren.ResetCamera()
            self.ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()
            self.ren.SetBackground(1,0,0)
            cam = self.ren.GetActiveCamera()
            cam.Elevation(10)
            cam.Azimuth(70)
            self.isploted = True


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(650,600), style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|
                  wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.p1 = p1(self.sp)
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(self.sp,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.sp.SplitHorizontally(self.p1,self.p2,470)

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Click on the Plot Button")

        self.plotbut = wx.Button(self.p2,-1,"plot", size=(40,20),pos=(10,10))
        self.plotbut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.plot)

    def plot(self,event):
        if not self.p1.isploted:
            self.p1.renderthis()
            self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Use your mouse to interact with the model")


app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = Frame(None,"Lights, Cameras, Action")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

There appears to be a useful example in C++ [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/Shadows): but I am struggling to understand the notation, afraid programming is not my background.

Many thanks for any pointers or tips, even if to tell that it is not possible at all and I need to rethink the approach.

Comment: Based on the class reference for the [renderer](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html) believe there should be a way of activating shadowing using the method:
'self.ren.UseShadowsOn()'
but this doesn't seem to funciton in VTK within python using either 5.10 or updated to 6.3